# How to search for substring preceded by a known substring

Tags: mysql, sql

Using `SQL`, I want to search for and retrieve sub-strings that are preceded by a known sub-string "XX." and ending in a " " or "'".

For example if I start with `CONTOOOH 788 XX. 3C, MNOP` I need to extract value `3C`

I've tried with *substring(input, posisiton, len)* but not sure about criteria of len since the len are vary.

```
select substring(input, position("XX." in input)+4, **???**)    
from tables 
where input like '%XX.%';
```

I am using MySQL.

[image]

```
Input
CONTOH LALALA 12 XX. 1 ABCD LALA NANA MAMA KAKA
CONTOH NANANANA 34 XX. 02 EFGH IJKL MN
CONTOOOH MAMAMA XX. 1A IJKL YOYO
CONTOOOH NANA XIXI 788 XX. 423C, MNOP QRSTU ASDF POIU
EXAMPLE BLA BLA HOHOHO 910 XX. A4, QRST ASDGHH
EXAMPLE ZZZ AAA BBB 1112 XX. BB5, UVWXASDGHH


Output
1
02
1A
423C
A4
BB5
```

Comment: Does the word of interest _always_ occur after the exact text `XX.`?  If not, can you articulate some rules for how we can find the text you want to extract?  Also, what version of MySQL are you using?  Do you have access to MySQL 8?

Comment: Correct, the word of interest always occur after the exact text XX. I'm using MySQL workbench 8.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option uses `SUBSTRING_INDEX` with `REPLACE`:

```
SELECT
    Input,
    REPLACE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(Input, 'XX. ', -1), ' ', 1), ',', '') AS Output
FROM yourTable;
```

[image]

### Demo

Here is how the string operations are working, step by step

```
CONTOOOH 788 XX. 3C, MNOP    - initial input
3C, MNOP                     - after first call to SUBSTRING_INDEX
3C,                          - after second call to SUBSTRING_INDEX
3C                           - after call to REPLACE, to remove the comma
```

Comment: This code only works when there is only one string in the end. But actually in my data there is inconsistent number string after the string I want to retrieve.
I've made edit my example table. thanks

Comment: `my example table may not represent the data` ... then you didn't ask the right question :-)

Comment: Yes, sorry Tim, I just made the correction for example table above. :)

Comment: @HarryPrawiro I patched my answer.  Let me know if this would work for you.

Comment: This time it's works! thanks for the help. Voted your answer. :)

Comment: all right, thanks again for guide me as I'm new with stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation for MySQL substring

> length    **Optional**. The forms without a len argument return a substring from string str starting at position pos.
>   https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring

Thus if your current code works to your liking except for length, simply omit it, and it will return the entire substring.